# Extracting the data from one Array into another array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an input array like this:

```
array (size=2)
 0 => 
array (size=3)
  'Vector Plus - 2`S' => int 12
  'Vector Plus - 4`S' => int 24
  'Date' => string '2014-06-01' (length=10)
1 => 
array (size=2)
  'Vector Plus - 4`S' => int 2
  'Date' => string '2014-06-02' (length=10)
```

but I want a output array from the above array to be like:

```
array(size 3)
 0=>
  array(size 3)
   0 => string 'Vector Plus - 2`S' (length=17)
   1 => string 'Vector Plus - 4`S' (length=17)
   2 => string 'Date' (length=4)
 1=>
   array(size 3)
  0=> int 12
  1=> int 24
  2=> string '2014-06-01'
 2=>
  array(size 3)
  0=> int 2
  1=> string 'undefined'
  2=> string '2014-06-02'
```

So how can I extract the data from input array into output array format?

Comment: That is a very odd format you are going for.  Have you made any attempt at all?

Comment: The format he is going for is not strange if you look at it with php5.5 and the new way of building arrays, trough using $array = [];. The structure he is expecting is odd tough.

Comment: yes,I have tried but it was quite a mess. Actually i want each unique key of the above array into a single array[0] and its value according to datewise. And if the same type key is not present in array[0], then it should be pushed into array as "undefined".

Comment: @Mike and Michal-sk please have a look. I have edited the format. Actually it does not matter about the format. The thing is to extract the data from intput array. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Michal-sk웃 I really did not speak clearly.  I was talking about the data structure being odd.  Not worried about whether someone wants to use the new array notation or not. Also worried that OP has not even shown an attempt at what is a pretty trivial task.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $prv_arr Contain your given array format...
and $arrnew is new array in new format

```
$arrnew = array();
array_push($arrnew,array ("Date","Vector Plus - 2's","Vector Plus - 4`S"));  
for ($i=0; $i<count($prv_arr);$i++)
array_push($arrnew,array ($prv_arr[$i]["Date"],$prv_arr[$i]["Vector Plus -      2's"],$prv_arr[$i]["Vector Plus - 4`S"]));
```

Comment: But how can i define "undefined" for the value that is not available for a particular key in unique date.